# Display Authorize Error Message in MVC from Action Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authorize

```
[Authorize]
        public ActionResult Delete(string id= null)
        {
            UserDetail userdetail = db.UserDetails.Find(id);
            db.UserDetails.Remove(userdetail);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

This Delete method will work only for authorized users. For unauthorized users it is showing Server Error. 
How to show Custom Authorization error message in this case so that it can be a user friendly error message.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Server error page. Instead I want to display a custom error message in the same view page, Ex: You are not authorized for this operation

Answer (score 0):

You can create customize authorization

```C#
  public class CustomAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
          protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {

            if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                // If the request is ajax request, replace with PartialViewResult
                filterContext.Result = new PartialViewResult
                {
                    ViewData = null;//pass whatever,
                    TempData = null;//pass whatever,
                    ViewName = "_partialView"; // whatever partialview
                };
            }

            if (request.IsJsonRequest())
            {
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
                {
                    Data = "Nice try buddy ;)";
                };
            }            

 filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
                {
                    controller = "Account",
                    action = "Logon",
                    ReturnUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl
                }));
        }
}
```